# Reference another json file in appsettings.json for ASP.NET Core configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration-files, asp.net-core-2.0

In 'the old days' using XML configuration it was possible to include partial configuration from another file like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms228154(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
<appSettings file="relative file name">
    <!-- Remaining configuration settings -->
</appSettings>
```

Now in ASP.NET Core I would like to share some configuration in `appsettings.Development.json` as well as for example `appsettings.Staging.json`. Is something like the `<appSettings file="">` did also available using the json configuration?

Comment: You can add as many JSON files as you like in your startup code.

Comment: Of course, but I'm trying to prevent duplication between json files themselves

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "prevent duplication". You don't need to have duplicate content in additional files, you just add new bits as required and the framework takes care of merging them into a larger config. Each additional file will override the values in a previous one if they were present, or will just add to it if not.

Comment: The Q is clear to me. web.config files i.e. allow you to external ref other config files [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/add-reference-external-config-files-in-webconfig1) Now, I have a host prj and a mirgrate prj and I have to maintain both.

Answer (score 16):

You can add mutliple configuration file in the Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings-Development.json", optional: false)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings-Staging.json", optional: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

See here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration
    ...

Comment: Sorry, but that's not my question. I need for example to include `appsettings-shared.json` into both `appsettings-Development.json` and `appsettings-Staging.json`

Comment: Can you keep those shared settings in a separate file and load it in your startup ? This way you don't have to include those settings in the others because you have them available all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add a file outside of the project solution folder ie "another file" I made it work by setting .SetBasePath("to whatever path where the settings file is") like so:

any-class-name.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace your-name
{
    static class ConfigurationManager
    {
        public static IConfiguration AppSetting { get; }
        static ConfigurationManager()
        {
            AppSetting = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath("C:/Users/Name/Documents/AnotherSettings/") //instead of .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I fail to understand why, when a question CLEARLY asks for `X`, people answer for `Y`. This is NOT what the OP asked for !

Comment: The question is `How to use a file like abcd.xyz` in config